# EventHandler stops after uploading a file to SharePoint with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scheduled-tasks

I am currently running a powershell script as a scheduled task every five minutes to upload files to SharePoint.

The script looks like this:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb ($rootUrl)
$spDocLibName = $destinationUrl

$spList = $spWeb.GetFolder($spDocLibName)

$spFiles = $spList.Files

$metadata = @{}

[...]

$spFile = $spFiles.Add($spDocLibName + "/" + $movedItem.Name, $movedItem.OpenRead(), $metadata, $true)
```

As it normally does when started this way the powershell instance is closed when the task is finished. Unfortunately the SharePoint event handlers are started in the context of the powershell, so they are cancelled when the powershell instance is closed.

My first attempt here was to start a sleep-command at the end of the script so powershell is still running when the following actions are running, but I don't think this is a good solution, because I don't know exactly how much time the event handler needs.

Now I would like to try leaving the powershell instance open and run the task always in this powershell instance. Is this possible and how?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You need to post your code so the SO community can advise you on how to keep the task going until it has done its job.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I added my code for the upload.

Comment: Have a look at this article, it's C# but should be easy enough to translate into PS: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101677/is-it-possible-to-wait-until-my-file-is-uploaded-in-document-library

Comment: If I understand that article correctly, it solves another problem. My problem is not that the event handler is called before the file is uploaded, but it is canceled when the powershell script is finished.